# Rate Of Divergence of Inverse Primes Using Only The Euler Product Formula

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The book *"Riemann's Zeta Function" by H.M. Edwards* on pages 1-2 discussed Euler's early work on primes, emphasising that some of his work was intuitive.

It says that Euler argued that:

- The harmonic series $\sum\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3} +\ldots$ not only diverges, but diverges like "the logarithm".
- Sum of inverse primes $\sum\frac{1}{p} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} +\frac{1}{5} +\ldots$ diverges like the logarithm of $\sum\frac{1}{n}$
- And so $\sum_{p<x}\frac{1}{p} \sim \ln(\ln(x))$, asymptotic equality.

Euler is actually quoted as using older notation "$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} +\frac{1}{5} +\ldots = \text{log}(\text{log}(\infty))$"

---

**My question is about each step of this argument:**

Q1. Is the first point is due to noting $\sum\frac{1}{n} < 1+ \int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{x}dx = 1+\ln(n)$? If so, how do we prove the difference between the continuous integral and the discrete becomes insignificant for large $n$?

Q2. I understand this is due to the well-known [Euler Product Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_the_Euler_product_formula_for_the_Riemann_zeta_function) $\sum_n\frac{1}{n} = \prod_p(1-\frac{1}{p})^{-1}$. Taking the logarithm of both sides, and using the series expansion for $(1-\frac{1}{p})^{-1}$, gives us a divergent $\sum\frac{1}{p}$ plus a convergent rest of series  $\sum\frac{1}{mp^m}$ for $m>1$. So  $\ln\sum_n\frac{1}{n}$ diverges like $\sum_p\frac{1}{p}$.

What is the relationship between $n$ in $\ln\sum_n\frac{1}{n}$ and $p$ in $\sum_p\frac{1}{p}$ ?

Q3. The final step depends on the relationship $p<n$ being valid in the previous point. I can't see how arguments about infinite series can be valid for $p<n$.

---

**Note:** I know there are more advanced modern methods for estimating the rate of divergence of $\sum\frac{1}{p}$ but I'm interested in this book's suggestion that Euler did it using simpler arguments.

Comment: In fact, the limit as $n$ goes to infinity of $\sum^n(1/m)-\int_1^n(1/x)\,dx$ exists. It's not hard to prove that for all $n$, $1/2<\sum^n(1/m)-\int_1^n(1/x)\,dx<1$, by drawing the graph of $y=1/x$ and putting in rectangles with base $[n,n+1]$ and height $1/n$.

Comment: Euler's argument is just an heuristic to predict the asymptotic of $\sum_{p\le x} p^{-1}$, in term of rigor and proof it is a nonsense, he never had any proof that $\sum_{p\le x} p^{-1}\sim \log \log x$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes for an analysis of Euler's proof of this.